# Ember error: No model was found

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I visit a route that has a model hook:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find("account_type");
  }
});
```

I get this error:

Error while processing route: register No model was found for 'account_type' Error: No model was found for 'account_type'

I have a file in models called account_type.js :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default  DS.Model.extend({
  type: DS.attr('string')
});
```

mock route:

```
  app.use('/api/account_type', accountTypesRouter);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using ember-cli, and if that's the case, the standard separator convention for names is dashes, not underscores. I think if you change the route to look for 'account-type' instead, that should fix it.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find("account-type");
  }
});
```

If that doesn't work, you might need to change the file name to `account-type.js` too.

**Edit**

It looks like [dasherized file names are required](http://www.ember-cli.com/#dasherized-file-and-folder-names-are-required).

Comment: what about my mock router shoudl I change it to: 
  app.use('/api/account-type', accountTypesRouter); from 
  app.use('/api/account_type', accountTypesRouter);

Comment: for some reason my mock only works when I have it as: **  app.use('/accountTypes', accountTypesRouter);**

Comment: @Beerlington: thanks, I was facing the same problem, using model name with camelCase, but after changed it to dashed format it works.